# Transparency problem with tga material/texture

Tags: materials, texturing, 3d-view

I am having a problem with a material/texture not showing up transparent as it should in blender 2.69. The material is from a tga file. I have a video showing the problem [here](http://knowledgecrazy.com/transparency_problem.webm) where the hair should be mostly transparent, but instead shows the default model color of gray.

It looks like it should when I right click on it, but when I select a different part of the model, it show incorrectly again.  I followed the steps in this [tutorial](http://bencrowder.net/art/blender-quicktips/transparent-textures/) and it got it so that it works when it is highlighted at least which is a nice, but it is still not working as can be seen when some other part is selected.

The blend file can be found [here](http://knowledgecrazy.com/zeptoblaster4.blend). Thank you in advance for any help that can be offered.

Answer (score 1):

Tick *Transparency* under *Display* in the *Object* tab. This will have the object's material display any transparency it has in the viewport sans the gray placeholder.

[image]

Comment: Hm, it seems that this doesn't fix the problem with the official 2.69 release. I notice that I have a slightly different layout in the display panel (Type is labeled Maximum draw type and in one row with Object Color), are you using a nightly build?

Comment: @stacker I was using 2.66, the panel has just been reorganized and I tested this in the latest and the official build of 2.69 and it works. It hides the outline by default so you might have to enable _Wire_ or _Bounds_ to select it easier after. http://pasteall.org/blend/25944

Answer (score 1):

If iKIsR's solution doesn't work for your case, you may then try to tweak the OpenGL ***Clip Alpha*** value in **User Preferences** window to fix the display in certain cases.

The "gray" color on the hair is the 3D View background color, not the model color. Besides, I know you are talking about the 3D View display issue, but the current hair cannot be actually rendered as trasparent, btw. You need to uncheck the ***Face Texture Alpha*** in **Options** panel, and check the ***Receive Transparent*** in **Shadows** panel. Hope it helps anyway.